# How to set ID of dynamic TextInput in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Very simple question I might just not be comprehending life,

```
self.ids.UpdateCustomer1.add_widget(TextInput(text='123',id=str('AddUserTextBox')))
```

Here is my code, I just want to set the id of a dynamic text box that pops up when a button is pressed. that all works fine, but whenever I reference AddUserTextBox.text it tells me its non-existent. or more specifically " NameError: name 'AddUserTextBox' is not defined"

Now I have tried setting id='AddUserTextBox' and also as id=AddUserTextBox and I have had no luck. all help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The `ids` are setup when your `.kv` file (or string) is first processed and is not updated after that. So your new `TextInput` widget id does not get added to the `ids`. You can work around that by doing:

```
import weakref
textinput = TextInput(text='123')
self.ids.UpdateCustomer1.add_widget(textinput)
self.ids['AddUserTextBox'] = weakref.ref(textinput)
```

The `weakref` is used because that is what kivy uses when it initially sets up the `ids` dictionary. This is not the best way to do it. It would be better just to keep a reference to your added `TextInput`.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

You cannot reference by using `self.ids.AddUserTextBox.text` or `self.ids['AddUserTextBox'].text` because the `id` created in Python code is not the same as `id` defined in kv file. The differences are as follow:

1. Python code: The value assigned to `id` is a string and it is not stored in `self.ids` dictionary.
2. kv file: The value assigned to `id` is a string and it is stored in `self.ids` dictionary.

[Kv language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

> Warning
>
> When assigning a value to id, remember that the value isn’t a string.
>   There are no quotes: good -> id: value, bad -> id: 'value'

[Kv language » Accessing Widgets defined inside Kv lang in your python code](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

> When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with
>   id’s and places them in this self.ids dictionary type property.

## Solution

Please refer to snippets, example, and output for details.

1. Instantiate a *TextInput* widget and assign it to `self.AddUserTextBox`
2. Add `self.AddUserTextBox` widget to `self.ids.UpdateCustomer1`
3. Referencing *TextInput's text* by `self.AddUserTextBox.text` or `root.AddUserTextBox.text`. Depending on where it was created.

### Snippets

```
self.AddUserTextBox = TextInput(text='123')
self.ids.UpdateCustomer1.add_widget(self.AddUserTextBox)
...
print(self.AddUserTextBox.text)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def add_user_text(self):
        self.AddUserTextBox = TextInput(text='123')
        self.ids.UpdateCustomer1.add_widget(self.AddUserTextBox)
        print(self.AddUserTextBox.text)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        text: 'Add User TextInput'
        on_release:
            root.add_user_text()

    GridLayout:
        id: UpdateCustomer1
        rows: 1
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: Although that works great, still doesnt let you access the .text property. unless there is something about ids that I dont understand. Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Comment: To reference the text use `self.AddUserTextBox.text` or `root.AddUserTextBox.text`. Depending on where it is created. There is no ids required.