# Kivy: can't access id of widget added with python (add_widget())

Tags: python, kivy

**Expected output:** ['name', 'age']

**Actual output:** ['name']

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        id: name
        text: "Bob"
'''

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
       box = Builder.load_string(KV)
       box.add_widget(Label(text="24", id="age"))
       print(list(box.ids.keys()))
       return box


if __name__ == "__main__":
   MyApp().run()
```

What can I do to get id of widget that I add with `add_widget` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ids` dictionary is created when a `kv` file (or string) is parsed. You cannot add an `id` to the `ids` dictionary by adding an `id` to a widget. However, you can manually add an `id` to the `ids`. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369722/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-textinput-in-kivy/51370359#51370359).

Comment: Thank you John Anderson, you are always giving answers to my questions. You have saved me hours of works since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add this to the official kivy Github !

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
KV = '''
ObjBoxLayout:
    Label:
        id: name
        text: "Bob"
'''

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
       box = Builder.load_string(KV)
       box.add_widget(Label(text="24"), key="age")
       print(list(box.ids.keys()))
       return box

class ObjBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_widget(self, widget, index=0, canvas=None, key=None):
        if key: self.ids[key] = widget
        super(ObjBoxLayout, self).add_widget(widget, index, canvas)




if __name__ == "__main__":
   MyApp().run()
```